# Yet another Failure Parsing XML: not well formed (invalid token) error

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

I've looked in all the other threads about the same issue and I still can't figure out what the problem is. I'm using Eclipse 4.2 and the latest Android SDK. Sorry to ask such a beginner question, and I really do appreciate whatever help you may be able to give. My code looks like this (I've marked the error-producing line with an `X`):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="paul.learning.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
X           <activity
                android:name=".MyFirstActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_my_first" 
                android:name="paul.learning.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have closed the `activity` element with `/>`.  Change it to this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyFirstActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_my_first" 
    android:name="paul.learning.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a ">" after the attributes in the `<application>` start tag.